# product price based on gold price or gold weight in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, product-prices

Hi guys,

I am a newbie to Magento and i'm Developing a Jewelry store with **Magento 2**.

In which i need to set product price based on gold price, making charge, gold weight etc. (No fixed prices, price depends on day to day gold price)

In order to get this i need to set a price formula. So my question is 
1. Is it possible to calculate price based on product attributes ?
2. If So, how can i do this ?

Please help me to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you specify, for which point you need to help? So everyone give suggestion or answer. Update your question to specific problem or help you need.

Comment: Edited my question for more clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2 provide functionlity to set custom product price before product add to cart, to archive this you need to used event in your extension. 
Event which is used here is "checkout_cart_save_before" event.

Create file [vendor][Extension]\etc\frontend\event.xml and specify this code for your event.

```
<event name="checkout_cart_save_before">
    <observer name="[Uniqe_event_name]" instance="[vendor]\[Extension]\Observer\AddtocartbeforeObserver" shared="false" />
</event>
```

Now create a file in [vendor][Extension]\Observer\AddtocartbeforeObserver.php

```
namespace [vendor]\[Extension]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddtocartbeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Do Your Code Login Here

        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

        $price = YOUR_PRICE; //SET YOUR CALCULATED NEW PRICE

        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

In observer file you get all the detail like options selected by user, product price etc, calculate new price according to logic and set product price show in above example.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Let me try with your suggession. But let me ask you one thing, How can i access product attribute values in this observer

Comment: You can access detail with the used of object $item.